# What's the difference between 'com.microsoft.azure' and 'com.azure'?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot

When creating a new Spring Boot project using `Spring Initializr` and adding `Azure Support`, it adds a dependency to `com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter`.

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter'
```

The [spring cloud documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-azure) says:

> The Azure Support entry contains auto-configuration support for Azure
> managed services [...]

Now I'd like to send and receive messages from `Azure Service Bus` and the documentation wants me to add a dependency to `azure-servicebus`.

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter'
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus'
```

Okay fine. When I now switch over to Microsoft and read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-samples) about Service Bus there, it mentions two libraries, where Microsoft states the second one is dated and legacy.

1. azure-messaging-servicebus (latest) `implementation 'com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.0.0'`
2. azure-servicebus (legacy) `'com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus'`

**Question**

1. Is the Spring Boot documentation just outdated?
2. I have read somewhere that libraries in `com.microsoft.com` are for managing the resource itself, while libraries in `com.azure` are for managing the data. Is this true?
3. What is meant by *auto-configuration* support?

As you can see I am very confused which dependencies I need to add. Also I don't get the difference between packages from `com.azure` and `com.microsoft.azure`.

Can someone please shed some light on this?